# Input of values in a dynamically allocated matrix - C

Tags: c, matrix, memory-management, dynamic, malloc

Working on a little console application that performs mathematical operations on values across matrices of similar dimensions. The CreateMatrix() function returns int** that gives the dimensions of the array, now I'm trying to take input and am running into errors. I've never used malloc before, so I'm thinking I used something incorrectly. I'll try to omit any code that you won't need in finding my issue.

```
    int rowInput, colInput;
    int** customA, customB;

    int main(void) {
        printf("\nEnter the number of Rows: ");
        scanf(" %i", &rowInput);
        printf("\nEnter the number of Columns: ");
        scanf(" %i", &colInput);
        customA = CreateMatrix(colInput, rowInput);
        for (int row = 0; row <= rowInput; row++) {
          for (int column = 0; column <= colInput; column++) {
            printf("Enter input for value at MatrixA[%d][%d]\n", row, column);
            scanf(" %i", &customA[row][column]);
          }
        }
        PrintMatrix(rowInput, colInput, customA);
        printf(" \n");
      }
    }
```

CreateMatrix(), and includes, are declared in my Header.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define Row 2
#define Col 5
#define Max 10

/**
*Dynamically allocate memory for custom matrix based on desired dimensions input
*@return int** to newly allocated matrix
**/
int** CreateMatrix(int colInput, int rowInput);

/**
*Checks input for matrix Row and columns exceeding maximum allowed
*
*/
int CheckMaximums(int *rowInput, int *colInput);
```

And CreateMatrix() is defined in my CLibrary.c that I've linked in CMake. Included CheckMaximums() just for your reference, since it's used in CreateMatrix. I've not had issues with that logic, though.

```
#include <Header.h>

int** CreateMatrix(int colInput, int rowInput) {
  int** customMatrix;
  CheckMaximums(&rowInput, &colInput);
  printf(" \n");
  customMatrix = (int**)malloc(rowInput);
  for (int i = 0; i < colInput; i++)
    customMatrix = (int*)malloc(colInput);
  return customMatrix;
}

int CheckMaximums(int *rowInput, int *colInput) {
  if (*rowInput > Max || *colInput > Max) {
    if (*rowInput > Max && *colInput > Max) {
      *rowInput = Max;
      *colInput = Max;
      printf("\nYour Row and Column sizes both exceed the maximum allowed values\n"
             "Row size has been set to max value (10)\n"
             "Column size has been set to max value (10)");
    } 
    else if (*rowInput > Max) {
      *rowInput = Max;
      printf("\nYour Row size exceeds the maximum allowed value\n"
             "Row size has been set to max value (10)\n");
    }
    else {
      *colInput = Max;
      printf("\nYour Column size exceeds the maximum allowed value\n"
             "Column size has been set to max value (10)\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance, I know this is a lot to look at, tried to reduce it to the bare minimum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in CreateMatirx malloc needs to know the total number of bytes to allocate. Multiply the number of elements desired by the size of each element.

```
customMatrix = malloc(rowInput * sizeof ( int*);//each element is a pointer to int
for (int i = 0; i < rowInput; i++)
    customMatrix[i] = malloc(colInput * sizeof int);//each element is an int
```

The first malloc allocates enough memory for `rowInput` pointers. Each pointer can be accessed like an array with indexes `customMatrix[0]` to `customMatrix[rowInput - 1]`.
The `for` loop iterates through each of those pointers and allocates enough memory for `colInput` integers.

in main, change the <= to < in the for loops otherwise you access beyond the allocated memory

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowInput; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < colInput; column++) {
```

the return of malloc and scanf should be checked as those functions can fail